# Is there a resource that gives a list of wild pets by zone?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've tried a number of addons and sites but I'm yet to find something that just tells me what wild pets are in which zone, grouped by zone.  Wowhead has some [crazy maps](http://www.wowhead.com/map#-3.2.50.50) but it doesn't give me the summary I'm looking for.

What I basically hope for is something like:

> Zone - Pets:
>
> - Dun Morogh - X, Y and Z
> - Tirisfal Glades - A, B and X
> - etc

Does anyone know of a resource like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I obtained this list from the [forums](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6080260469):

```
Bloodmyst Isle 6
   Chicken
   Infected Squirrel
   Rat
   Infected Fawn
   Ravager Hatchling
   Skunk
Hrothgar's Landing 0
Arathi Highlands 6
   Prairie Dog
   Hare
   Rat
   Tiny Twister
   Cat
   Grasslands Cottontail
Gilneas City 4
   Spider
   Rat
   Cat
   Roach
Westfall 7
   Snake
   Chicken
   Shore Crab
   Prairie Dog
   Mouse
   Westfall Chicken
   Tiny Harvester
Desolace 10
   Topaz Shale Hatchling
   Red-Tailed Chipmunk
   Elfin Rabbit
   Stone Armadillo
   Rock Viper
   Horny Toad
   Rat
   Amethyst Shale Hatchling
   Forest Moth
   Roach
Zul'Drak 6
   Gundrak Hatchling
   Water Waveling
   Spider
   Arctic Hare
   Huge Toad
   Snake
Tanaris 7
   Sand Kitten
   Rattlesnake
   Stinkbug
   Stripe-Tailed Scorpid
   Gold Beetle
   Silithid Hatchling
   Sea Gull
Northern Stranglethorn 16
   Snake
   Polly
   Roach
   Razzashi Hatchling
   Water Snake
   Crimson Moth
   Hyacinth Macaw
   Beetle
   Panther Cub
   Parrot
   Tree Python
   Lizard Hatchling
   Adder
   Strand Crab
   Forest Spiderling
   Long-tailed Mole
Borean Tundra 4
   Oily Slimeling
   Borean Marmot
   Arctic Hare
   Shore Crab
Swamp of Sorrows 9
   Spider
   Toad
   Swamp Moth
   Huge Toad
   Rat
   Moccasin
   Strand Crab
   Parrot
   Water Snake
Deepholm 13
   Topaz Shale Hatchling
   Twilight Beetle
   Crimson Shale Hatchling
   Elementium Geode
   Crimson Geode
   Crystal Beetle
   Amethyst Shale Hatchling
   Emerald Shale Hatchling
   Twilight Spider
   Tiny Shale Spider
   Stowaway Rat
   Deepholm Cockroach
   Fungal Moth
Azuremyst Isle 6
   Chicken
   Rabbit
   Rat
   Grey Moth
   Squirrel
   Skunk
Gilneas 10
   Snake
   Spider
   Toad
   Roach
   Cat
   Rat
   Chicken
   Strand Crab
   Squirrel
   Skunk
Eastern Plaguelands 9
   Mr. Grubbs
   Spider
   Beetle
   Infected Fawn
   Cockroach
   Infected Squirrel
   Bat
   Black Rat
   Festering Maggot
Teldrassil 11
   Forest Moth
   Red-Tailed Chipmunk
   Spider
   Elfin Rabbit
   Hawk Owl
   Toad
   Rabbit
   Fawn
   Crested Owl
   Squirrel
   Great Horned Owl
Elwynn Forest 13
   Chicken
   Stormwind Rat
   Orange Tabby Cat
   Black Lamb
   Squirrel
   Cornish Rex Cat
   Cat
   Rabbit
   Bombay Cat
   Fawn
   Sea Gull
   Spider
   Silver Tabby Cat
Un'Goro Crater 9
   Ash Lizard
   Beetle
   Cockroach
   Fire Beetle
   Tree Python
   Long-tailed Mole
   Parrot
   Diemetradon Hatchling
   Spotted Bell Frog
Mulgore 6
   Prairie Dog
   Rabbit
   Gazelle Fawn
   Mouse
   Mountain Cottontail
   Brown Prairie Dog
Felwood 6
   Tainted Cockroach
   Tainted Rat
   Beetle
   Tainted Moth
   Toad
   Minfernal
Western Plaguelands 4
   Blighthawk
   Rabbit
   Squirrel
   Black Rat
Wetlands 13
   Mountain Skunk
   Tiny Bog Beast
   Chicken
   Crimson Whelpling
   Highlands Skunk
   Mouse
   Rabbit
   Dark Whelpling
   Razormaw Hatchling
   Squirrel
   Water Snake
   Black Rat
   Toad
Jade Forest 20
   Spirebound Crab
   Wild Crimson Hatchling
   Mirror Strider
   Masked Tanuki
   Garden Moth
   Shrine Fly
   Leopard Tree Frog
   Fishy
   Silkbead Snail
   Jungle Darter
   Grove Viper
   Bucktooth Flapper
   Coral Adder
   Garden Frog
   Temple Snake
   Jumping Spider
   Sandy Petrel
   Wild Golden Hatchling
   Masked Tanuki Pup
   Wild Jade Hatchling
Mount Hyjal 16
   Fire-Proof Roach
   Carrion Rat
   Twilight Beetle
   Squirrel
   Blue Mini Jouster
   Bat
   Grotto Vole
   Ash Lizard
   Death's Head Cockroach
   Elfin Rabbit
   Gold Mini Jouster
   Rock Viper
   Fire Beetle
   Rabbit
   Forest Moth
   Alpine Chipmunk
Silverpine Forest 8
   Snake
   Blighted Squirrel
   Infected Fawn
   Squirrel
   Infected Squirrel
   Rat
   Rabbit
   Toad
Stonetalon Mountains 10
   Mountain Skunk
   Spider
   Roach
   Rabbit
   Rabid Nut Varmint 5000
   Rat
   Coral Snake
   Highlands Skunk
   Venomspitter Hatchling
   Alpine Chipmunk
Moonglade 4
   Forest Moth
   Rabbit
   Squirrel
   Festival Lantern
Thousand Needles 4
   Ancona Chicken
   Roach
   Black Rat
   Twilight Iguana
Winterspring 12
   Mountain Skunk
   Azure Whelpling
   Winterspring Cub
   Alpine Hare
   Crystal Spider
   Robo-Chick
   Rabid Nut Varmint 5000
   Rabbot
   Snowy Owl
   Spider
   Highlands Skunk
   Alpine Chipmunk
Hinterlands 7
   Cockroach
   Hare
   Spider
   Rat
   Brown Marmot
   Jade Oozeling
   Maggot
Cape of Stranglethorn 16
   Cockatiel
   Senegal
   Baby Ape
   Roach
   Wharf Rat
   Razzashi Hatchling
   Parrot
   Crimson Moth
   Hyacinth Macaw
   Beetle
   Lizard Hatchling
   Tree Python
   Rat
   Strand Crab
   Forest Spiderling
   Long-tailed Mole
Zangarmarsh 3
   Firefly
   Snake
   Tiny Sporebat
Dustwallow Marsh 10
   Snake
   Spider
   Toad
   Chicken
   Dark Whelpling
   Squirrel
   Spawn of Onyxia
   Mouse
   Black Rat
   Darting Hatchling
Badlands 8
   King Snake
   Beetle
   Rattlesnake
   Spiky Lizard
   Dark Whelpling
   Stripe-Tailed Scorpid
   Gold Beetle
   Black Rat
Darkshore 7
   Withers
   Rabbit
   Rat
   Gilnean Raven
   Shimmershell Snail
   Squirrel
   Darkshore Cub
Loch Modan 5
   Snake
   Rat
   Little Black Ram
   Squirrel
   Roach
Blade's Edge Mountains 6
   Rabbit
   Brown Marmot
   Skittering Cavern Crawler
   Scalded Basilisk Hatchling
   Squirrel
   Rock Viper
Dread Wastes 10
   Grinder
   Silent Hedgehog
   Yakrat
   Amber Moth
   Aqua Strider
   Crunchy Scorpion
   Clouded Hedgehog
   Resilient Roach
   Rapana Whelk
   Emperor Crab
Townlong Steppes 6
   Grassland Hopper
   Mongoose
   Kuitan Mongoose
   Yakrat
   Amber Moth
   Mongoose Pup
Ruins of Gilneas 4
   Rat
   Spider
   Toad
   Squirrel
Kun-Lai Summit 9
   Szechuan Chicken
   Zooey Snake
   Tolai Hare Pup
   Plains Monitor
   Alpine Foxling
   Summit Kid
   Alpine Foxling Kit
   Tolai Hare
   Prairie Mouse
Tirisfal Glades 11
   Chicken
   Spider
   Bat
   Roach
   Lost of Lordaeron
   Rabbit
   Rat
   Undercity Cockroach
   Feline Familiar
   Maggot
   Undercity Rat
Wandering Isle 0
Valley of the Four Winds 4
   Softshell Snapling
   Terrible Turnip
   Shy Bandicoon
   Wild Silkworm
Durotar 7
   Creepy Crawly
   Pint-Sized Pink Pachyderm
   Spiny Lizard
   Adder
   Water Snake
   Toad
   Hare
Ahn'Qiraj 2
   Beetle
   Roach
Silithus 5
   Spiky Lizard
   Beetle
   Qiraji Guardling
   Scarab Hatchling
   Rock Viper
Molten Front 3
   Searing Scorchling
   Hyjal Bear Cub
   Crimson Lasher
Sholazar Basin 4
   Snake
   Stunted Shardhorn
   Squirrel
   Biletoad
Tol Barad 5
   Wharf Rat
   Rustberg Gull
   Fox Kit
   Squirrel
   Snake
Grizzly Hills 6
   Mountain Skunk
   Fawn
   Imperial Eagle Chick
   Mouse
   Grizzly Squirrel
   Highlands Skunk
Twilight Highlands 13
   Shore Crab
   Water Snake
   Highlands Turkey
   Grizzly Squirrel
   Highlands Mouse
   Rattlesnake
   Cockroach
   Huge Toad
   Twilight Spider
   Elementium Geode
   Yellow-Bellied Marmot
   Black Rat
   Wildhammer Gryphon Hatchling
Icecrown 18
   Mulgore Hatchling
   Argent Gruntling
   Ammen Vale Lashling
   Roach
   Enchanted Broom
   Durotar Scorpion
   Elwynn Lamb
   Mechanopeep
   Argent Squire
   Spider
   Shimmering Wyrmling
   Teldrassil Sproutling
   Black Rat
   Sen'jin Fetish
   Cockroach
   Tirisfal Batling
   Scourged Whelpling
   Dun Morogh Cub
Lost Isles 3
   Frog
   Strand Crab
   Rat
Netherstorm 12
   Crimson Snake
   Senegal
   Mana Wyrmling
   Brown Rabbit
   Cat
   Red Moth
   Blue Dragonhawk Hatchling
   Fledgling Nether Ray
   Undercity Cockroach
   Mouse
   Nether Roach
   Siamese Cat
Uldum 5
   Locust
   Leopard Scorpid
   Tol'vir Scarab
   Mac Frog
   Elementium Geode
Duskwood 10
   Chicken
   Rat Snake
   Squirrel
   Roach
   Rabbit
   Widow Spiderling
   Dusk Spiderling
   Mouse
   Black Rat
   Skunk
Vashj'ir 0
Hillsbrad Foothills 13
   Chicken
   Red-Tailed Chipmunk
   Spider
   Snowshoe Hare
   Toad
   Maggot
   Black Tabby Cat
   Rabbit
   Rat
   Infested Bear Cub
   Huge Toad
   Squirrel
   Singing Sunflower
Ashenvale 10
   Forest Moth
   Beetle
   Toad
   Roach
   Frog
   Rat
   Maggot
   Strand Crab
   Squirrel
   Rusty Snail
Ghostlands 7
   Snake
   Larva
   Rat
   Maggot
   Spirit Crab
   Toad
   Spider
Redridge Mountains 6
   Fledgling Buzzard
   Rabbit
   Chicken
   Mountain Cottontail
   Redridge Rat
   Roach
Hellfire Peninsula 2
   Adder
   Flayer Youngling
Southern Barrens 1
   Giraffe Calf
Kezan 6
   Rabid Nut Varmint 5000
   Rabbot
   Black Rat
   Strand Crab
   Robo-Chick
   Roach
Howling Fjord 16
   Snake
   Squirrel
   Roach
   Turkey
   Skunk
   Chicken
   Shore Crab
   Toad
   Maggot
   Spider
   Rabbit
   Rat
   Fjord Rat
   Fjord Worg Pup
   Devouring Maggot
   Pengu
Isle of Quel'Danas 0
Shadowmoon Valley 3
   Ash Viper
   Tainted Cockroach
   Fel Flame
Eversong Woods 8
   Snake
   Toad
   Golden Dragonhawk Hatchling
   Rabbit
   Ruby Sapling
   Cat
   Silver Dragonhawk Hatchling
   Red Dragonhawk Hatchling
Terokkar Forest 9
   Snake
   Miniwing
   Warpstalker Hatchling
   Magical Crawdad
   Squirrel
   Rat
   Stripe-Tailed Scorpid
   Nether Ray Fry
   Skunk
Vale of Eternal Blossoms 5
   Effervescent Glowfly
   Golden Civet
   Golden Civet Kitten
   Dancing Water Skimmer
   Eternal Strider
Crystalsong Forest 7
   Ghostly Skull
   Obsidian Hatchling
   Rat
   Calico Cat
   Albino Snake
   Squirrel
   Rabbit
Deadwind Pass 1
   Restless Shadeling
Scarlet Enclave 0
Blasted Lands 4
   Fire Beetle
   Adder
   Scorpling
   Spider
Burning Steppes 6
   Tiny Flamefly
   Fire Beetle
   Dark Whelpling
   Ash Viper
   Cockroach
   Lava Crab
Searing Gorge 4
   Molten Hatchling
   Fire Beetle
   Ash Spiderling
   Lava Crab
Northern Barrens 5
   Chicken
   Cheetah Cub
   Adder
   Prairie Dog
   Biletoad
Feralas 6
   Snake
   Rabbit
   Nether Faerie Dragon
   Sprite Darter Hatchling
   Emerald Whelpling
   Squirrel
Storm Peaks 5
   Highlands Skunk
   Arctic Hare
   Arctic Fox Kit
   Mountain Skunk
   Spider
Azshara 12
   Turquoise Turtle
   Spider
   Twilight Beetle
   Squirrel
   Roach
   Rabbit
   Rabid Nut Varmint 5000
   Twilight Spider
   Rat
   Robo-Chick
   Shore Crab
   Skunk
Krasarang Wilds 11
   Jungle Grub
   Shore Crab
   Spiny Terrapin
   Wanderer's Festival Hatchling
   Feverbite Hatchling
   Amethyst Spiderling
   Luyu Moth
   Tiny Goldfish
   Mei Li Sparkler
   Savory Beetle
   Sea Gull
Dun Morogh 18
   Snake
   Alpine Hare
   Crystal Spider
   Squirrel
   Roach
   Pint-Sized Pink Pachyderm
   Snow Cub
   Irradiated Roach
   Spider
   Toad
   Maggot
   Snowshoe Rabbit
   Rabbit
   Rat
   Adder
   Strand Crab
   Black Rat
   Long-tailed Mole
Nagrand 8
   Prairie Dog
   Squirrel
   Clefthoof Runt
   Rabbit
   Rat
   Adder
   Snake
   Toad
Wintergrasp 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to [warcraftpets.com](http://www.warcraftpets.com/guides/pets/wow-pets-by-zone/?zones=Eastern+Kingdoms&events=show&battle=show).  They have a `pets by zone` page.  Make sure both Wild Pets and Event Pets are shown.  If you hide Event pets, they don't seem to show all the pets you want to see.

Comment: They don't have battle pets in there yet. Hopefully they add them at some point, but I was hoping for something currently usable. :)

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by battle pets.  There are certainly battle pets in there.  There are also wild pets, by zone.

Comment: Oops, my apologies - I did mean wild pets, not battle pets. I've updated my question. On that site, when I look at some of the zones that definitely have wild pets they don't appear to be listed, even when I select "Wild Pets: Show".  Elwynn Forest, for example, only lists the cats sold - it doesn't list Black Lamb, Fawn, Rabbit, etc, that you can battle and tame in that zone.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on that at least lists them - [PetJournal Enhanced](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/pet-journal-enhanced).  I am not sure about something displayed with the in game map, but would be a good recommendation to the add-on.